# Back button without using navigation controller in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I haven't embedd navigation controller with my view controller. Now i'm using a code to go back to home screen to with the use of back button but there nothing appears, i don't know why. I don't want to use navigation controller in my vc. This is the code,

```
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"car_marker.png"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self.navigationController
                                                              action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

It should look like this only,
[image]

Comment: show your code related to this popViewControllerAnimated

Comment: but there nothing appears - means your barbuttons does not visible

Comment: Than where will the back button will be shown? @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: You cannot pop to a `viewcontroller` untill and unless your `viewcontroller` is embedded in an `UINavigationController`.

Comment: is there  not anyway that we cannot use navigation controller and move back to home screen from a vc. @iPeter

Comment: Bar buttons are added to navigation bar . You can use normal buttons and present controller. You can not push because you are not using navigation controller..

Comment: can u explain this in answer? @TusharSharma

Comment: You can set you view controller as `rootViewcontroller`. But you cannot push or pop until you are using a `Navigation Stack`.

Comment: At first tell me the reason why you don't want to use an `UINavigationController`.

Comment: add one manual UIview in top and add one UIbutton instead of barbutton

Comment: Check the image , i want my page to look like this only. If i use navigation bar then its look will be wrong. @iPeter

Comment: Okay let me try. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: Dude!! Where you don't want to show `navigationbar` just hide it by calling `self.navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true`.

Comment: And without `NavigationController` how can you manage your project flow?

Comment: You need NavigationController to manage the stack of view controllers. The navigation controller is always initialized as a root view controller and you can always jump to this view controller from any child view controller by calling 'popToRootViewController'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to change your approach because you cannot pop without a `navigation controller`.

You should embed your `viewcontroller` into `navigation controller` and then you can hide with `[[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` and then you can add any kind of custom button to perform pop action.

For adding a custom back button to your view

```
- (void)addCustomBackButtonToView
{
    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 44.0f, 30.0f)];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popVC) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:backButton];
}

- (void) popVC{
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: How can i change the nav bar color to transparent so that my backgroung image looks like the screenshot i had added above? @Paras Gorasiya

Comment: You just need to hide navigation bar instead of making it transparent. Please follow my pasted code and you will get what you want but in order to have perform pop action you will need to add a custom back button at top left position.

Comment: how can we use custom popup back button according to ur code? @Paras Gorasiya

Comment: Its not working, its just disappearing the nav bar but not showing an back button. @Paras Gorasiya

Comment: Please show us how are you adding the custom back button in your code.

Comment: So you will also have to add an image of the back button in your bundle otherwise you will see nothing.

Comment: Its not working again, i have added all ur code in one vc but not working  and i have image of back button also. @Paras Gorasiya

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    
    UIButton *backButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 20, 44.0f, 30.0f)];
    [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(popVC) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [self.view addSubview:backButton];
}

Comment: How are you adding all the other objects into the same view? I guess you are adding those after adding back button. So your back button is hidden. You should add [self.view bringSubviewToFront:backButton] after adding all the other objects.

Comment: @HamzaImran No problem, it would be great if you accept the answer and upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your navigation controller by below code `self.navigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true`

and use **swipegesture option** to move back, even though you have to use navigation controller,@**iPeter** has a valid point.

Comment: karthik - are you seen this line `I haven't embedd navigation controller with my view controller` in question

Comment: yes, i saw, thats why I have mention to embed navigation controller, if you are not using the related view you can use present the viewController simply.sorry man if I'm wrong

Comment: @karthik you have given the answer already that by using a UIView along with button he can dismiss the view.

Comment: how can i use swipe gestures? @KarthiKeyan

Comment: You can see lots of example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39764088/swipe-gesture-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 0):

1) Add two ViewControllers make first as initial controller(entry point).

2) Add view on both ViewController with size you wish to have.

3) Add buttons on both views as subviews.

4) create segue from firstButton ->(use show) -> second controller.

5) From second ->(use show) -> first controller.

see the image below-:

[image]

**This is not preferred way of doing pop/push. You must use Navigation Controller(that works like a stack for controllers you push) that will provide you default Back button or you can create custom .**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not push or pop view controllers as you are not using the Navigation controller. Try using Present & dismiss controller which can called from any controller Instace.

Step 1 : Present to " Controller which is shown with no navigation bar but back button"

```
[self presentViewController:@"<ViewControllerToBePresented>" animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Step 2: add backBatton in ViewDidLoad

-(void)addBack{

```
UIButton *backBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f)];
[backBtn setTitle:@"back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissViewController) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:backBtn];
```

}

Step 3: Dismisscontroller to go back to previous scene

-(void) dismissViewController{

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

}