# How to remove long gesture in UIcollectionViewCell particular cell on selection cell?

Tags: ios, swift

I have added `Long gesture` like this:

```
longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongGesture))

longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.25
collectionview.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
```

How to remove long gesture?

Comment: can anyone help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove all gesture recognizers from a UIView in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206452/how-to-remove-all-gesture-recognizers-from-a-uiview-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Find the cell and list of gestures added to the cell and remove the one  you want ..

```
let cell:UICollectionViewCell =  collectioView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(row: 5, section: 0))!


        for ges in cell.gestureRecognizers!{
            if ges is UILongPressGestureRecognizer{
               cellView.removeGestureRecognizer(ges)
            }
        }
```

Comment: i want to remove long gesture on collectionview cell suppose 5 row

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the gesture before cell is getting ready to display.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let gesture = cell.gestureRecognizers?.filter({ (gesture) -> Bool in return  gesture is UILongPressGestureRecognizer }).first {
            cell.removeGestureRecognizer(gesture)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the gesture recognizer for the whole collection view.

So, If you want only one cell not to respond for long gesture, for that particular cell disable gesture recognizers(use touchesBegan call back to check the touch event happened within the cell and if it is, handle the event by code as you wish).

If you want this functionality on multiple cells then add gesture recognizer for each cells which requires the recognizer separately.